# Dynamic access of method based on external field in Spring boot

Tags: java, reflection, spring-boot

We have multiple external variables in application.yml in spring boot application and i want to access this variable from my java code and based on the field value I want to redirect the call to various functions.

Example:

```
String externalVariable1 abc;
String externalVariable2 xyz;

method: if(string == abc) {
call function1; }
else {
call function2; }
```

Now problem here is there might be further addition to external variable in furture, I want to write robust method which should be adaptable to future addition to external variable without changing my core code. i might add the functionality as part of helper methods.

All I can think of reflection way, Can you guys help me with better approach given i am using spring boot application.

Comment: Have you read the documentation regarding external configuration using yaml? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml

Comment: I dont think its about YML, it could be properties file as well. All i need to understand if i get a external field from properties file, hat design can i follow to in my java method so that to have minimal code change in case we add further external variable in properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do reflection for this. Instead, wrap `function1`/`function2` into some kind of *strategy* object:

```
interface Strategy {
   void doStuff();
}

class Function1 implements Strategy {
   void doStuff() {
       function1();
   }
}

class Function2 implements Strategy {
   void doStuff() {
       function2();
   }
}
```

Then, register all of these with some factory-style class:

```
class StrategyFactory {

  private Strategy defaultStrategy = new Function2();

  Map<String, Strategy> strategies = ....
  strategies.put("abc", new Function1());
  ...

  Strategy getStrategy(String key) {
     return strategies.getOrDefault(key, defaultStrategy);
  }
}
```

Finally, use it:

```
factory.getStrategy(valueFromYaml).doStuff();
```

Make `key` a more complex object than just `String` if you need to accommodate for more complicated scenarios, or use a more sophisticated way of selecting a strategy than a map lookup.

If you don't know the available strategies before runtime (e.g. if the configuration for these comes from a DB or files) keep only the class name of the `Strategy` implementation in a map:

```
Map<String, String> strategyClassNames = ...;
strategy.put(keyFromDB, valueFromDB);
...
```

and use it by:

```
Class<? extends Strategy> strategy =  Class.forName(strategyClassNames.get(key));
strategy.newInstance().doStuff();
```